# Restrictions when working with unbounded streams

Tags: java, java-stream

Are their any restrictions when working with unbounded(infinite) streams in java? if so, what are the restrictions?

Comment: I recommend against using `max()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call a [*terminal operation*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps) that isn't *short-circuiting*, unless you've applied a *short-circuiting intermediate operation*.

Short-circuiting terminal operations:

- [`findAny()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findAny())
- [`findFirst()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst())
- [`allMatch​(Predicate<? super T> predicate)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch(java.util.function.Predicate))
- [`anyMatch​(Predicate<? super T> predicate)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch(java.util.function.Predicate))
- [`noneMatch​(Predicate<? super T> predicate)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#noneMatch(java.util.function.Predicate))

Short-circuiting intermediate operations:

- [`limit​(long maxSize)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit(long))
- [`takeWhile​(Predicate<? super T> predicate)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#takeWhile(java.util.function.Predicate)) *(Java 9+)*

E.g. the following will never return:

```java
int max = IntStream.iterate(0, i -> (i + 1) % 100)
        .max().getAsInt();
```

But this will:

```java
int max = IntStream.iterate(0, i -> (i + 1) % 100)
        .limit(15)
        .max().getAsInt();
```

For the operations that take a `Predicate`, there is still a risk of the terminal operation never returning.

Comment: Note that `allMatch` will short-circuit if the answer is `false`, but will run forever if it's `true`.  `anyMatch` and `noneMatch` are similar.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Same for `takeWhile`, hence the note at the end of the answer.

Comment: @LouisWasserman that applies to all these terminal operation that they can not guaranty a termination for every imaginable scenario. The point is, short-circuiting terminal operations might terminate while the others won’t terminate for sure.